# Webhooks in Rails Controller for Shopify App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, webhooks

I have a webhooks controller which listens for when a new customer is created in Shopify.

```
def customer_created_callback
    @first_name = params[:first_name]
    @last_name = params[:last_name]
    @email = params[:email]

    @customer = Customer.new(first_name: @first_name, last_name: @last_name, email: @email)

    if @customer.save
      redirect_to customers_url
    else
      puts "error"
    end

  end
```

1. I am wondering if I should be creating the customer in this controller action. It seems like I should be handling the customer creation in Customer#create. But I'm not sure if it's a good idea to be passing all these params to a new action.
2. What's a good example of where I should be redirecting_to? I thought the idea of a webhook is that it's happening in the background so no page is actually going to be rendered..

Hope those make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like I should be handling the customer creation in Customer#create

Where the code lives is up to you but you must keep it [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself). Personally I like to use [Service Objects](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) since they make testing easier.

> What's a good example of where I should be redirecting_to?

You need to return a 200 response with no content:

`render :nothing => true, :status => 200`

Typically you'll use a background job which will use the service object when it runs. This post on [Webhook Best Practices](http://www.shopify.com.au/technology/5154662-webhook-best-practices) is an excellent resource to get acquainted with the in's and out's of web hooks.